# Forms Authentication works locally, but not on dev server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

I know Forms Authentication is old, but when I run the web application locally using IIS Express, everything works well. But when I publish it to our development/test server, it just reloads the page. The dev server is running IIS 6.

One more thing to note, locally it runs as localhost:50264/Login. On the dev server, the url is more like http://dev1.server.com/op/webapp/Account/Login.

I notice that both of the cookies have the path "/". I did try to set change that by having this in my local web.config:

```
<add key="CookiePath" value="/" />
```

And then when I publish to our dev server it changest to:

```
<add key="CookiePath" value="http://dev1.server.com/op/webapp/" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```

That didn't seem to work.

In another thread that I found in Stack Overflow, someone suggested to add this to the :

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="FormsAuthenticationModule" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

That didn't work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE: 9/29/2016**

I removed the CookiePath app setting and, instead made an adjustment to the authentication node. In my Web.config I now have:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

And in my Web.Debug.config I have:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" path="/op" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
</authentication>
```

Finally, when I create the cookie:

```
var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    1,
    user.Email,
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(14),
    true,
    userData,
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
```

When I deploy to the dev server, I check the web.config there and it did transform the forms node correctly.

When I go to login, I enter my credentials and it still refreshes the Login page. With the Chrome extension "EditThisCookie" I still see that the path of the cookie is "/". It doesn't recognize the change AT ALL. Even when I manually set the path of authTicket path to "/op" the cookie STILL has the path as "/". I have no idea what's going on. Ugh...

Comment: What is `CookiePath`? How it is related to your forms cookies? It doesn't look like a part of the built-in infrastructure.

Comment: No matter if it's local or on the dev server it has the correct domain, but the path is always "/"

Comment: What you have here is somehing hat looks like taken out of the `appSettings` section. What I try to tell you is that there is no built in mechanism for which this arbitrary setting is related to Forms Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I use forms authentication also, here's my settings. You didn't show all your forms Authentication code, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Web.Config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="members/login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="120" />
</authentication>
```

Then I set the cookie in the code behind when the user logs in.

```
  Dim authCookie As HttpCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(iMembersID, False)
  Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value)
  Dim newTicket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration, ticket.IsPersistent, "Member")
  authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket)
  Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie)
```

Then I test to see if they are authenticated on all pages that require the user to be logged in.

```
    If Request.IsAuthenticated Then
        Dim ident As FormsIdentity = CType(User.Identity, FormsIdentity)
        If ident IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = ident.Ticket
            Dim userDataString As String = ticket.UserData

            Select Case ticket.UserData
                Case "Member"
                    m_MemberLoggedIn = ident.Name
                Case Else
                    Response.Redirect("~/members/login/", True)
            End Select


        Else
            Response.Redirect("~/members/login/", True)
        End If
```

**Update 9/29:**

Check to make sure the IIS Authentication mode to set to Anonymous

Comment: Since you seem to be using the WebForms, here is a link to the docs on WebForms Authorization https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx

Comment: Every page is not checked, just the pages that require authorization (That's how forms authentication works).  The OP Question is about Forms authentication and the issue he is having. This was not a question about, what's the best approach on how to handle authentication, which will be a lengthy discussion.

Comment: I made changes to the web config and the Authentication Ticket and that didn't help any on the dev server.

Comment: @henry That is why I comment your answer rather than provide an answer to OP's question. Your answer promotes bad approach as you seem to redo something that is already available out of the box. I've never ever seen anyone doing that by themselves in all my 15 years of enterprise asp.net coding.

Comment: @ajtatum Can you post the rest of the code and the current settings in the web.config

Comment: @henry I've updated my original post with more information.

Comment: Right now Anonymous and Forms Authentication are checked. Should just Anonymous be checked?

Comment: I have both checked on mine,  Try removing the `~/` from the login url

Comment: Also give your cookie a name, look at mine `name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"`

Answer (score 0):

I went the easy way out and asked our IT Dept to create a subdomain so the path of the cookie will always be "/". Not an answer, but it's what I did.